# How to assign 1 user to 1 order id?

Tags: php

I want to divide data into multiple users.

```
<?php
    
    $users = array('13','15','16','16','17','20');
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    
    $i = 1;
    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        foreach ($users as $value) {
            echo $data['OrderId'] .":". $value;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

output is

```
Order ID     :   UserId
405-6219270-3721912  :  13  
405-6219270-3721912  :  15  
405-6219270-3721912  :  16  
405-6219270-3721912  :  17  
405-6219270-3721912  :  20  
403-5995684-2353914  :  13  
403-5995684-2353914  :  15  
403-5995684-2353914  :  16  
403-5995684-2353914  :  17  
403-5995684-2353914  :  20  
404-1894735-7034722  :  13  
404-1894735-7034722  :  15  
404-1894735-7034722  :  16  
404-1894735-7034722  :  17  
404-1894735-7034722  :  20  
406-7756082-9574748  :  13  
406-7756082-9574748  :  15  
406-7756082-9574748  :  16  
406-7756082-9574748  :  17  
406-7756082-9574748  :  20  
171-7214409-3467567  :  13  
171-7214409-3467567  :  15  
171-7214409-3467567  :  16  
171-7214409-3467567  :  17  
171-7214409-3467567  :  20  
405-7442385-9605918  :  13  
405-7442385-9605918  :  15  
405-7442385-9605918  :  16  
405-7442385-9605918  :  17  
405-7442385-9605918  :  20
```

But I Want this output

```
Order ID     :   UserId
405-6219270-3721912  :  13  
403-5995684-2353914  :  15  
404-1894735-7034722  :  16  
406-7756082-9574748  :  17  
171-7214409-3467567  :  20  
405-7442385-9605918  :  15  
171-7214409-3467569  :  16  
171-7214409-3467570  :  17  
171-7214409-3467571  :  20
405-7442385-9605972  :  15  
405-7442385-9605973  :  16  
405-7442385-9605973  :  17  
405-7442385-9605974  :  20
```

Why my loop iteration four-time instead of one?

Comment: What does your data look like, is it possible that there would be more users than order-ids? What is the expected output if there are more order ids than users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a nested loop as you do, this will for each order form the file, output each user.

What you can do instead is use 1 loop (reading the input file) and modulus (`%`) of the line number (`$i`) and output a user per order...

```
$userCount = count($users);
$i = 0;
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    echo $data[0] .":". $users[$i % $userCount] . PHP_EOL;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each order ID (data), you iterate over all the users. Instead, you could use something like this:

```php
<?php
$users = array('13','15','16','16','17','20');
$handle = fopen($_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name'], 'r');

// Iterate over the users.
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== null) {
        echo $data['OrderId'] . ':' . $user;
    }
}
?>
```

Iterate over the users, for each user, if there is still csv data, consume that csv data and print order ID and user ID.

Comment: This would only run `count($users)` times therefore not consuming all the csv file :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly sure, but it looks like that is the desired output. On the list the OP sent, there is only one output line per user, and it seems like the rest of the CSV data should just be ignored. Maybe I am misinterpreting the "But I want this output".

Comment: I am guessing that the OP did not spend long on his sample data and expected results, there are multiple user numbers in the "But I want this output" if you look closer and ignore the fact OP has only one `13` and the 2 `16`'s in the `$users` array dont feature  twice like they should do according to the users array :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are right, I never noticed the multiple 16s, I should have looked better, I thought it was just a list with one occurrence of each user ID.